# Azure Serverless SQL Serverless Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I Created SQL Server Database in Azure which is serverless and tried to access it using my SQL Server Management Studio in my local but I couldn't get it work.

It always gives me this message:

[image]

I tried to whitelist also my IP in Azure but still I get the same result.

[image]

Is there a possible way to make it connect?

Comment: Have you read and followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms)?

Comment: Also on Serverless, if the database is paused, the first connection attempt will fail, while the database unpauses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless#connectivity

Comment: what's your SQL sever Location and your local internet location?

Comment: Hi Leon, sorry if I misunderstood.. The SQL Server that I created resides on Azure and I'm trying to access it thru MS SQL Management Studio installed in my laptop.

Comment: Did you read my answer below? It's all explained there. I doubt if location has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Is the database currently online or paused?

I'll repeat the text from @David Browne's link:

> > If a serverless database is paused, then the first login will resume the database and return an error stating that the database is unavailable with error code 40613. Once the database is resumed, the login must be retried to establish connectivity. Database clients with connection retry logic should not need to be modified.

So;

- Assuming the database is paused, this is normal operation
- Please read docs
- You need to retry after the database starts OR manually pre-start it using the Powershell provided in the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless#connectivity

And yes, you also need to whitelist your IP address as you have already done.

Obviously this flavour of SQL is unsuitable for some types of applications - there is more information in the link - I suggest you read the whole thing.